# 504 error in Nginx+Passenger for long running Rails processes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, timeout

We have a file import Rails process that runs for a long time. Since switching to Nginx from Apache, we began getting 504 timeout errors after exactly 10 minutes each time -- we don't have a 10 minute limit set anywhere in our nginx.conf. I've looked at several questions/answers on stackoverflow but haven't found a solution. I don't want to go back to Apache since we love Nginx's simplicity and speed but this is driving me crazy since I've tried every timeout config option in Nginx that I could find :-)

This is currently what I have in our nginx.conf file -- what am I doing wrong?

```
http {
    keepalive_timeout 300 300;
    keepalive_requests 20;
    send_timeout 30m;
    proxy_read_timeout 30m;
    proxy_connect_timeout 30m;
    ...

    server {
        listen 80;
    ...
    server {
        listen 443;
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out 10 minutes is a Nginx and Passenger hard-coded limit; got this email directly from the Passenger folks:

> The 10 minute timeout is hardcoded into the Phusion Passenger module.
>   But 10 minutes is actually already the maximum timeout that Nginx
>   allows so there is no way to increase it.

Answer (score 0):

You left out the important part of your config, but I assume you're probably doing a fastcgi_pass and not a proxy_pass. You'll want to look at these directives client_header_timeout, client_body_timeout and send_timeout.

Comment: Thanks, MTeck. Actually, the reason client_header_timeout and client_body_timeout aren't in the config is because I've already tried those and they didn't work. send_timeout is in the config. One other thing: I assume the timeout fields all go in the http config block, not server blocks? Thanks in advance.